# mypy complains about TypedDict inside attrs class having Incompatible types

Tags: python, mypy, python-attrs

I have a TypedDict `DictWithOnlyX` inside an attrs data class `Example` where mypy complains about the type returned from the `getdict()` method of my class, even though the return type is declared:

```
from typing_extensions import TypedDict
from attr import attrs, attrib, Factory, fields

DictWithOnlyX = TypedDict('DictWithOnlyX', {"x": str})

@attrs
class Example(object):
    name: str = attrib(default="")
    dx = attrib(factory=DictWithOnlyX)

    def getdict(self) -> DictWithOnlyX:
        return self.dx  # <-- mypy compains
```

mypy complains `error: Incompatible return value type (got "DictWithOnlyX", expected "DictWithOnlyX")`

The irony is, when solve the mypy problem by declaring the type of the `attrib()` I get another mypy error - whack a mole!

```
@attrs
class Example(object):
    name: str = attrib(default="")
    dx: DictWithOnlyX = attrib(factory=DictWithOnlyX)  # <-- mypy compains

    def getdict(self) -> DictWithOnlyX:
        return self.dx
```

mypy complains `error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "DictWithOnlyX", variable has type "DictWithOnlyX")`

Both versions of the above code *run* OK. Python 3.7.5.

Both error messages are mysterious because they seem self contradictory - how can types that are (reported to be) the same be 'Incompatible'?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a mypy bug to me. But I'm surprised it works that well at all, since you're side-stepping attrs' typing support completely! The idiomatic way to define the class would be

```py
@attrs(auto_attribs=True)
class Example(object):
    name: str = ""
    dx: DictWithOnlyX = Factory(DictWithOnlyX)
```

But that causes the same error message.